# Plugin for "Was This Helpful" at end of post?

Tags: plugins

I'd like to use a Wordpress instance as a product help & faq platform.

I'm wondering if there is a lightweight plugin that provides a "yes/no" voting option at the end of a post, to which I'd use the question "Was this post helpful to you?" I can then go into the admin panel to see the total number of yes's and no's per post.

Does one like that exist?

I've found a multitude of "Digg-like" up/down plugins, but they are far too complex for what I'm looking for. I've looked at [Vote-It-Up](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/vote-it-up/) and [WP-Polls](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/vote-it-up/), which both seem like they can be hacked to accomplish what I want, but I wanted to first check to see if there was a ligher weight solution out there.

Thanks in advance for the suggestions.

Comment: take a look at WP-PostRatings http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postratings-my/

Comment: That appears to support a 1-5 rating, like WP-Polls and the like. I'm looking for more of a 0/1 or "Yes/No" rating system.

Comment: UPDATE: After a lot of research the past day, it appears Vote It Up is the best, but you need to hack it a bit. There is no clear-cut plugin designed just for this. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/vote-it-up/

Comment: Google Analytics Survey for High Rated Content "Was this content helpful?" http://www.9lessons.info/2016/04/google-analytics-survey-for-high-rated.html

Answer (score 8):

I meant you should look at [WP-PostRatings](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postratings/) it has more then just star based rating :

[image]

And if that's not good you can use your own images.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you for the feedback. I'll be trying it out! I wish I could give a 1+ to you but I don't have a high enough rep yet :-)